# ANR force close when running this code

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

This code is causing ANR force close any idea how to improve this code? i try with asynctask and i cant make it work in this code :

What i try to do here is **updater** activity will check for latest version and if got new version it will pop up **alertdialog** to ask user to update in the market

```
public class Updater extends Activity {

    private int newVerCode = 0;
    private String newVerName = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        if (getServerVerCode()) {
            int vercode = Config.getVerCode(this);
            if (newVerCode > vercode) {
                doNewVersionUpdate();

            } else {
                notNewVersionShow();
            }
        }

    }
//check version using json
    private boolean getServerVerCode() {
        try {
            String verjson = NetworkTool.getContent(Config.UPDATE_SERVER
                    + Config.UPDATE_VERJSON);
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(verjson);
            if (array.length() > 0) {
                JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(0);
                try {
                    newVerCode = Integer.parseInt(obj.getString("verCode"));
                    newVerName = obj.getString("verName");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    newVerCode = -1;
                    newVerName = "";
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            return false;

        }
        return true;
    }
//Found No new version
    private void notNewVersionShow() {
        Updater.this.finish(); // End updater activity
    }

//Found New version
    private void doNewVersionUpdate() {
//Display alertdialog
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an AsyncTask - yes. In `doInBackground` you can add the code from `getServerVerCode()` and in `onPostExecute` everything in the `if (getServerVerCode())`.
`doInBackground` can return boolean so you know in `onPostExecute` what the result is.
Something like this:

> ```
> private class GetServerVerCode extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> { 
>
>     @Override 
>     protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
>       try {
>         String verjson = NetworkTool.getContent(Config.UPDATE_SERVER
>                 + Config.UPDATE_VERJSON);
>         JSONArray array = new JSONArray(verjson);
>         if (array.length() > 0) {
>             JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(0);
>             try {
>                 newVerCode = Integer.parseInt(obj.getString("verCode"));
>                 newVerName = obj.getString("verName");
>             } catch (Exception e) {
>                 newVerCode = -1;
>                 newVerName = "";
>                 return false;
>             }
>         }
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>
>         return false;
>
>     }
>     return true;
>     } 
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
>         if (result) {
>             int vercode = Config.getVerCode(this);
>             if (newVerCode > vercode) {
>                 doNewVersionUpdate();
>
>             } else {
>                 notNewVersionShow();
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: wow ! thanks ! that was fast, I was still trying to implement it